# Why does wrapping os_log() cause doubles to not be logged correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, logging

Consider the following example:

```
import Foundation
import os.log

class OSLogWrapper {

    func logDefault(_ message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        os_log(message, type: .default, args)
    }

    func testWrapper() {
        logDefault("WTF: %f", 1.2345)
    }
}
```

If I create a new instance of `OSLogWrapper` and call `testWrapper()`

```
let logger = OSLogWrapper()
logger.testWrapper()
```

I get the following output in the Xcode console:

```
2018-06-19 18:21:08.327979-0400 WrapperWTF[50240:548958] WTF: 0.000000
```

I've checked everything I can think of and I can't make heads or tails of what's going wrong here. Looking through the documentation isn't yielding anything helpful.

Comment: try `%@` instead of `%f`

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The compiler implements variadic arguments by casting each argument to the declared variadic type, packaging them into an `Array` of that type, and passing that array to the variadic function. In the case of `testWrapper`, the declared variadic type is `CVarArg`, so when `testWrapper` calls `logDefault`, this is what happens under the covers: `testWrapper` casts `1.2345` to a `CVarArg`, creates an `Array<CVarArg>`, and passes it to `logDefault` as `args`.

Then `logDefault` calls `os_log`, passing it that `Array<CVarArg>` as an argument. **This is the bug in your code.** The bug is quite subtle. The problem is that `os_log` doesn't take an `Array<CVarArg>` argument; `os_log` is itself variadic over `CVarArg`. So Swift casts `args` (an `Array<CVarArg>`) to `CVarArg`, and sticks that casted `CVarArg` into **another** `Array<CVarArg>`. The structure looks like this:

```
Array<CVarArg> created in `logDefault`
  |
  +--> CVarArg (element at index 0)
         |
         +--> Array<CVarArg> (created in `testWrapper`)
                |
                +--> CVarArg (element at index 0)
                       |
                       +--> 1.2345 (a Double)
```

Then `logDefault` passes this new `Array<CVarArg>` to `os_log`. So you're asking `os_log` to format its first element, which is (sort of) an `Array<CVarArg>`, using `%f`, which is nonsense, and you happen to get `0.000000` as output.  (I say “sort of” because there are some subtleties here which I explain later.)

So, `logDefault` passes its incoming `Array<CVarArg>` as one of potentially many variadic parameters to `os_log`, but what you actually want `logDefault` to do is pass on that incoming `Array<CVarArg>` as the entire set of variadic parameters to `os_log`, without re-wrapping it. This is sometimes called “argument splatting” in other languages.

Sadly for you, Swift doesn't yet have any syntax for argument splatting. It's been discussed more than once in Swift-Evolution ([in this thread, for example](https://forums.swift.org/t/variadic-parameters-that-accept-array-inputs/12711/11)), but there's not yet a solution on the horizon.

The usual solution to this problem is to look for a companion function that takes the already-bundled-up variadic arguments as a single argument. Often the companion has a `v` added to the function name. Examples:

- `printf` (variadic) and `vprintf` (takes a `va_list`, C's equivalent of `Array<CVarArg>`)
- `NSLog` (variadic) and `NSLogv` (takes a `va_list`)
- `-[NSString initWithFormat:]` (variadic) and `-[NSString WithFormat:arguments:]` (takes a `va_list`)

So you might go looking for an `os_logv`. Sadly, you won't find one. There is no documented companion to `os_log` that takes pre-bundled arguments.

You have two options at this point:

- Give up on wrapping `os_log` in your own variadic wrapper, because there is simply no good way to do it, or
- Take Kamran's advice (in his comment on your question) and use `%@` instead of `%f`. But note that you can only have a single `%@` (and no other format specifiers) in your message string, because you're only passing a single argument to `os_log`. The output looks like this:

  ```
  2018-06-20 02:22:56.132704-0500 test[39313:6086331] WTF: (
      "1.2345"
  )
  ```

You could also file an enhancement request radar at https://bugreport.apple.com asking for an `os_logv` function, but you shouldn't expect it to be implemented any time soon.

So that's it. Do one of those two things, maybe file a radar, and move on with your life. Seriously. Stop reading here. There's nothing good after this line.

---

Okay, you kept reading. Let's peek under the hood of `os_log`. It turns out the implementation of the Swift `os_log` function is part of the [public Swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/os/os_log.swift):

> ```
> @_exported import os
> @_exported import os.log
> import _SwiftOSOverlayShims
>
> @available(macOS 10.14, iOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0, tvOS 12.0, *)
> public func os_log(
>   _ type: OSLogType,
>   dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle,
>   log: OSLog = .default,
>   _ message: StaticString,
>   _ args: CVarArg...)
> {
>   guard log.isEnabled(type: type) else { return }
>   let ra = _swift_os_log_return_address()
>
>   message.withUTF8Buffer { (buf: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) in
>     // Since dladdr is in libc, it is safe to unsafeBitCast
>     // the cstring argument type.
>     buf.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(
>       to: CChar.self, capacity: buf.count
>     ) { str in
>       withVaList(args) { valist in
>         _swift_os_log(dso, ra, log, type, str, valist)
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

So it turns out there **is** a version of `os_log`, called `_swift_os_log`, that takes pre-bundled arguments. The Swift wrapper uses `withVaList` (which is documented) to convert the `Array<CVarArg>` to a `va_list` and passes that on to `_swift_os_log`, which is itself also part of the [public Swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/os/os.m#L333). I won't bother quoting its code here because it's long and we don't actually need to look at it.

Anyway, even though it's not documented, we can actually call `_swift_os_log`. We can basically copy the source code of `os_log` and turn it into your `logDefault` function:

```
func logDefaultHack(_ message: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, _ args: CVarArg...) {
    let ra = _swift_os_log_return_address()
    message.withUTF8Buffer { (buf: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) in
        buf.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: buf.count) { str in
            withVaList(args) { valist in
                _swift_os_log(dso, ra, .default, .default, str, valist)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works. Test code:

```
func testWrapper() {
    logDefault("WTF: %f", 1.2345)
    logDefault("WTF: %@", 1.2345)
    logDefaultHack("Hack: %f", 1.2345)
}
```

Output:

```
2018-06-20 02:22:56.131875-0500 test[39313:6086331] WTF: 0.000000
2018-06-20 02:22:56.132704-0500 test[39313:6086331] WTF: (
    "1.2345"
)
2018-06-20 02:22:56.132807-0500 test[39313:6086331] Hack: 1.234500
```

Would I recommend this solution? No. **Hell** no. The internals of `os_log` are an implementation detail and likely to change in future versions of Swift. So don't rely on them like this. But it's interesting to look under the covers anyway.

---

One last thing. Why doesn't the compiler complain about converting `Array<CVarArg>` to `CVarArg`? And why does Kamran's suggestion (of using `%@`) work?

It turns out these questions have the same answer: it's because `Array` is “bridgeable” to an Objective-C object. Specifically:

- [Foundation (on Apple platforms) makes `Array` conform to the `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` protocol.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSArray.swift#L27) It implements bridging of `Array` to Objective-C by returning an `NSArray`.
- [Foundation also makes `Array` conform to the `CVarArg` protocol](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSArray.swift#L167).
- The `withVaList` function asks each `CVarArg` to [convert itself to its `_cVarArgEncoding`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/VarArgs.swift#L422).
- [The default implementation of `_cVarArgEncoding`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Foundation.swift#L90), for a type that conforms to both `_ObjectiveCBridgeable` and `CVarArg`, returns the bridging Objective-C object.
- The conformance of `Array` to `CVarArg` means the compiler won't complain about (silently) converting an `Array<CVarArg>` to a `CVarArg` and sticking it into another `Array<CVarArg>`.

This silent conversion is probably often an error (as it was in your case), so it would be reasonable for the compiler to warn about it, and allow you to silence the warning with an explicit cast (e.g. `args as CVarArg`). You could file a bug report at https://bugs.swift.org if you want.

Comment: Dude... wow.... This is the best answer I've ever gotten on on StackOverflow, and I've been here for a while. I had a hunch I was running into a subtlety of Swift's handling of variadic arguments so thank you.

Comment: For anyone trying to use `_swift_os_log*` functions, you'll now end up with "Use of unresolved identifier" errors.

Comment: @zgosalvez Looking at the latest Swift source for os_log and you'll see that you now need to `import _SwiftOSOverlayShims`

Comment: My app was crashing from this same issue with os_signpost and I couldn't figure out how to convert the [CVarArg] back to something that os_signpost() would properly interpret. Thanks for the workaround (even if it is a hack). I'll post my code for os_signpost in an answer below in case anybody wants it.

Comment: Rob, you have opened the hell gate here. Cheers!

Comment: The Swift source code appears to have moved here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/os/os_log.swift

Comment: For Swift 5.2 implementation of os_log : https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-5.2-branch/stdlib/public/Darwin/os/os_log.swift

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment to Rob Mayoff's answer above, for anybody experiencing the same kind of issue with `os_signpost()`, here is a wrapper class I made around it:

```
import Foundation
import os
import _SwiftOSOverlayShims

public final class Signpost {

    private final let log: OSLog

    public init(log: OSLog) {
        self.log = log
    }

    public final func begin(name: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, idObject: AnyObject? = nil) {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            signpost(.begin, dso: dso, name: name, idObject: idObject)
        }
    }

    public final func begin(name: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, idObject: AnyObject? = nil, _ format: StaticString, _ arguments: CVarArg...) {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            signpost(.begin, dso: dso, name: name, idObject: idObject, format, arguments)
        }
    }

    public final func event(name: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, idObject: AnyObject? = nil) {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            signpost(.event, dso: dso, name: name, idObject: idObject)
        }
    }

    public final func event(name: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, idObject: AnyObject? = nil, _ format: StaticString, _ arguments: CVarArg...) {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            signpost(.event, dso: dso, name: name, idObject: idObject, format, arguments)
        }
    }

    public final func end(name: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, idObject: AnyObject? = nil) {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            signpost(.end, dso: dso, name: name, idObject: idObject)
        }
    }

    public final func end(name: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, idObject: AnyObject? = nil, _ format: StaticString, _ arguments: CVarArg...) {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            signpost(.end, dso: dso, name: name, idObject: idObject, format, arguments)
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    private final func signpost(_ type: OSSignpostType, dso: UnsafeRawPointer = #dsohandle, name: StaticString, idObject: AnyObject? = nil) {
        guard log.signpostsEnabled else { return }
        let signpostID = getSignpostId(forObject: idObject)
        os_signpost(type, dso: dso, log: log, name: name, signpostID: signpostID)
    }

    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    private final func signpost(
        _ type: OSSignpostType,
        dso: UnsafeRawPointer,
        name: StaticString,
        idObject: AnyObject? = nil,
        _ format: StaticString,
        _ arguments: [CVarArg])
    {
        // This crazy mess is because [CVarArg] gets treated as a single CVarArg and repassing a CVarArg... actually passes a [CVarArg]
        // This was copied from the publicly available Swift source code at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/os/os_signpost.swift#L40
        // THIS IS A HACK
        guard log.signpostsEnabled else { return }
        let signpostID = getSignpostId(forObject: idObject)
        guard signpostID != .invalid && signpostID != .null else { return }
        let ra = _swift_os_log_return_address()
        name.withUTF8Buffer { (nameBuf: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) in
            // Since dladdr is in libc, it is safe to unsafeBitCast
            // the cstring argument type.
            nameBuf.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: nameBuf.count) { nameStr in
                format.withUTF8Buffer { (formatBuf: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) in
                    // Since dladdr is in libc, it is safe to unsafeBitCast
                    // the cstring argument type.
                    formatBuf.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: formatBuf.count) { formatStr in
                        withVaList(arguments) { valist in
                            _swift_os_signpost_with_format(dso, ra, log, type, nameStr, signpostID.rawValue, formatStr, valist)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    private final func getSignpostId(forObject idObject: AnyObject?) -> OSSignpostID {
        if let idObject = idObject {
            return OSSignpostID(log: log, object: idObject)
        }
        return .exclusive
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a wrapper for os_log that could log errors to crashlytics in case the type was of `.error`. My project is iOS 13 so I needed to to use the older `os_log` syntax. As Rob Mayoff mentioned there is an issue with implicit conversion from `CVarArg...` to `Array<CVArg>` causing issues when passed to the `os_log` method.

For me creating a simple switch on the count of the the args and doing separate calls to `os_log` for each count, taking out every argument from the array and passing it to `os_log` separately fixed the issue. The code is verbose, but it does the job for me.

```swift
func log(_ message: StaticString, log: OSLog = .default, type: OSLogType = .default, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        switch args.count {
        case 0:
            os_log(message, log: log, type: type)
        case 1:
            os_log(message, log: log, type: type, args[0])
        case 2:
            os_log(message, log: log, type: type, args[0], args[1])
        case 3:
            os_log(message, log: log, type: type, args[0], args[1], args[2])
        case 4:
            os_log(message, log: log, type: type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3])
        case 5:
            os_log(message, log: log, type: type, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4])
        default:
            assertionFailure("Currently only up to five arguments are supported")
        }
        // log error to crashlytics
    }
```